# is there a better and a faster way to copy from CPU memory to GPU using thrust?

Tags: cuda, thrust

Recently I have been using thrust a lot. I have noticed that in order to use thrust, one must always copy the data from the cpu memory to the gpu memory.
 Let's see the following example :

```
int foo(int *foo)
{
     host_vector<int> m(foo, foo+ 100000);
     device_vector<int> s = m;
}
```

I'm not quite sure how the `host_vector` constructor works, but it seems like I'm copying the initial data, coming from `*foo`, twice - once to the host_vector when it is initialized, and another time when `device_vector` is initialized. Is there a better way of copying from cpu to gpu without making an intermediate data copies? I know I can use `device_ptr`as a wrapper, but that still doesn't fix my problem.
thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of `device_vector`'s constructors takes a range of elements specified by two iterators. It's smart enough to understand the raw pointer in your example, so you can construct a `device_vector` directly and avoid the temporary `host_vector`:

```
void my_function_taking_host_ptr(int *raw_ptr, size_t n)
{
  // device_vector assumes raw_ptrs point to system memory
  thrust::device_vector<int> vec(raw_ptr, raw_ptr + n);

  ...
}
```

If your raw pointer points to CUDA memory, introduce a `device_ptr`:

```
void my_function_taking_cuda_ptr(int *raw_ptr, size_t n)
{
  // wrap raw_ptr before passing to device_vector
  thrust::device_ptr<int> d_ptr(raw_ptr);

  thrust::device_vector<int> vec(d_ptr, d_ptr + n);

  ...
}
```

Using a `device_ptr` doesn't allocate any storage; it just encodes the location of the pointer in the type system.

Comment: the argument size_t n specify the number of elements in the vector , and should not be in size_t type name , size_t usually specify the data length in bytes.

Comment: That's an odd comment. `size_t` is to specify the size of things. Chances are good that `thrust::device_vector<T>::size()` ultimately returns `size_t`. See [`std::size_t`'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)